# XNA Release becoming unresponsive

Tags: debugging, xna, publish

When I run the release, published, or debug version of my game, it becomes unresponsive when the window is not active. It only runs correctly when using F5 debug mode. Nothing I have tried has had any effect. Has anyone ever experienced this before or knows how to fix this?

Comment: XNA will run slower when it's not in focus, usually at a max of 40fps, and it will look choppy. Since I don't know how (or why) to fix this, I'll just drop this comment. Actually... Why do you want the game to perform when out of focus?

Comment: I don't care for it to, but I were to alt tab out for any reason, it will crash when they come back (Most of the time). I've tried messing with isActive, but that does not help.

Comment: Crash where, how? That's the real issue. Update the question. My XNA title does not crash if you minimize it, or leave it out of focus and come back.

Comment: It will become unresponsive I should say, it doesn't necessarily crash per say. Keep in mind this happens in all places but the F5 build. Frequently when the window is not active, in whatever form that may be, it becomes unresponsive, sometimes instantly. It also tends to flash white for a frame every 10 or 15 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your code. Can you reproduce the issue with a minimal XNA project?

Comment: I've never had this problem before, so I don't know if I can.

Comment: The strange thing is, the sounds continue to work as normal and on queue, which gives me the impression that the game is continuing underneath, but is not responding on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this with my game now. No idea how to fix the problem. Attaching a debugger to the process that is "not responsive" actually makes it start responding again. Serious Heisenbug. :(

Looks like this is exactly what is happening to us: [XNA app not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160187/xna-app-not-responding)

> Turns out I was checking Mediaplayer.State in an Update() method, and
>   due to my profiler, I found the issue. MediaPlayer.State is an
>   expensive enum to retrieve, and once I removed that block it no longer
>   hangs.

I just made a static handler to maintain my own copy of the state instead.

```
    static Audio()
    {
        MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>((sender, e) => { mediaPlayerState = MediaPlayer.State; });
    }
```